# Pointer Confusion with C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, data-manipulation

I am very confused with c++ pointers and reference operators. My main confusion is the following (simple ) code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void changeInt(int &a)
{
    a *= 3;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    changeInt(n);
    cout << n << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Mainly, I am confused as to why changing the address (&a) changes the actual variable (n). When I first attempted this problem this was my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void changeInt(int &a)
{
    *a *= 3;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    changeInt(n);
    cout << n << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

But this gives me an error. Why is it that when I change the address it changes the variable, but when I change the value pointed by the address I get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example is not valid C++, you can only dereference a pointer (or an object whose type overload `operator*`, which is not your case).

Your first example pass the parameter by **reference** (`int &a` is not "the address of a", it is a reference to a), which is why a change to `a` really is a change to the object being passed by the function (in you case, `n`)

Comment: @Asad-ullahKhan : no it doesn't : the page talks about the `&` operator, but your are not using it (you are declaring a reference, with `int &`)

Comment: OHHH that makes much more sense! Thanks you!

Comment: @Asad-ullahKhan in code: `int a = b & c;` you do not think that address of `c` is doing something to b, do you?

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand (`&`) in that context means a *reference*, not the "address". E.g.:

```
int some_int;

int & a = some_int; // Declare 'a', a reference to 'some_int'

int * p = &some_int; // '&' in this context is "the address of" 'some_int'
```

A reference is equivalent to a pointer in many ways, but it behaves like a value type.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) and the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand indicates that a variable is passed by reference to your function -- but inside the function the variable is treated as if it were passed by value. This is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), to make writing code that accepts references simpler to understand.